# What is the best way to optimize a big jquery POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

My problem is that after breaking the KB size on a jquery POST, the sending time is mostly bigger than 1 sec.

Is there a good way to optimize that?

And why it takes so long to send, so less data?

Comment: How much data are you sending?

Comment: 3.4 KB and it takes 2.27 Sec sending time

Comment: What about other non-cached requests? How long do they take?

Comment: 3.4kb is nothing, the problem should be something else.

Comment: @Mic: unless he's on extremely slow dial up (2400 baud rate anyone?) ;)

Comment: I have 11Mbit dialup, and 100mbit server. PINGS taking 25 ms. Other POSTS with for example 140 BYTE taking 27MS sending time .

Comment: @maka, do you use Chrome profiler for instance to check where the time si lost?

Comment: @maka, I didn't use FF for long to develop, but I think Webkit/Chrome provides a far better trace of what happens and when in a page.

Comment: Can you try to do the same post using a different tool, e.g. `curl`?

Comment: 3.4kb taking 2+ seconds points to a network problem.  What is the ping time of the server receiving the POST request?  Is there a firewall between?  Is there a router between or is it on the same subnet. (Sometimes routers stall incoming post requests).

Comment: Can you post the code sending the request?

Comment: Test the case with curl or a post form with the needed fields. I don't think the problem is jquery. I think the receiving script answers to slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, but in PHP. The thing is when you're sending POST requests with a lot of (or large) parameter values (larger than 1Kb if I remember correctly), HTTP tries to optimize the requests by sending "Expect: 100" header directive.
Meaning: *wait for code 100 before sending the second part (those large parameters)*. In my case this was exactly 2 seconds. I solved this by sending the "Expect: " header directive.

If you look in the Net tab of your FireBug, is there by and chance the an Expect parameter in the Request Header?

You can manually add the header like this (if you're using the ajax jQuery function):

```
$.ajax
(
    {
        url: "return.php",
        headers:
        {
            'Expect': ''
        }
    }
);
```

I might be completely wrong, but this sounded too familiar for me to stay silent...

Comment: This might explain what I'm talking about http://pilif.github.com/2007/02/the-return-of-except-100-continue/ http://haacked.com/archive/2004/05/15/http-web-request-expect-100-continue.aspx